# How to design a class correctly that uses explicit interface inheritance and operator overloading

Tags: c#, .net, interface, architecture, operator-overloading

I like to always define my classes using explicit interface inheritance and a private constructor so that i force clients to use the interface rather than newing up the class directly. I've never found the need to use operator overloading in the past but now i have a class where its a perfect fit. Unfortunately i found out that you must use static methods to overload operators which means you can't define them on the interface.

Why don't i like this?

1. Having to cast and object everytime you want to use an operator: `(IMyObject)object1++;`
2. You can't pass in the interface to the overloading function:

   ```
   public static bool operator ==(IMyObject a, IMyObject b)
   {
       return a.Equals(b);
   }
   ```

   doesn't work.

   You must define it with the implementation:

   ```
   public static bool operator ==(MyObject a, MyObject b)
   {
       return a.Equals(b);
   }
   ```

The first defect i hit was that `Equals()` didn't work. `Equals()` just calls GetHashCode() which was defined using Explicit interface inheritance which was calling `System.Object.GetHashCode()` rather than the one i had defined through explicit interface inheritance:

```
 int IMyObject.GetHashCode()
 {
     return _value.GetHashCode();
 }
```

I could have just override GetHashCode on the object and call `(IMyObject)this._value.GetHashCode();` but that seems really messy.

I know that you can use an abstract class instead of an interface and declare your overloads on your operators in the abstract class. To be honest i don't know if i like this but maybe its the best way? I don't want to have clients to cast to be able to use different functionality on my class and i also don't want anyone to run into a defect like i did.

To bad the language team didn't design operator overloading so that you could use virtual methods but i'm sure they had their reasons

EDIT:
I've decided to go against my best practice here and have clients new up the class directly instead of using an interface. I prefer over having to constantly casting to use different functionality of the class. I'll leave the question here in case someone can come up with a good solution in the future.

Comment: interface equality imho is ambiguous. For example: `Cat` and `Dog` implement `IAnimal`. Is `Cat` and `Dog` equals?

Comment: I have to respectfully disagree. Yes in your example it wouldn't make sense but say you have IPerson and you have the following classes that implement it: Manager, Executive, & Employee, & Consultant. You have a collection of IPerson. Would you like to have to know the type of each IPerson so you could cast it and use the '=='? You might say use SSN to see if they are equal. I my class though i need to implement more operators than just '==' like '+=1', ' ++', '--', ect... which the clients will use a LOT. A lot of times your just separating implementation/interface so your  instaces that

Comment: implement the interface are always the same class

Comment: Well, the question still remains the same though: is manager same with executive, or is employee same with consultant? In one case they can be the same, and in other case they aren't. That's why oop does not support equality in interface level. As fact, in most of linq operation they accept `IComparer` or `IEqualityComparer` to handle such case, instead of using hashcodes.